# Как получить один редирект вместо двух?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, seo

Дано правило для редиректа со страниц без слэша на страницы со слэшем:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

И правило для редиректа на `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Сейчас при запросе `URL` **http**://site.com/info происходит два 301 редиректа:

```
URL запроса:http://site.com/info
Код состояния: 301

URL запроса:https://site.com/info
Код состояния:301
```

Как объединить эти два правила, чтобы редирект происходил один раз?

Answer (score 0):

Никак, думается - если не делать редирект по протоколу, то при запросе страницы сразу со слешем не будет редиректа на https.

Comment: У меня получилось достичь желаемого результата.
`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/ [L,R=301]`
Но я не знаю насколько верное мое решение.

Comment: @Олег Нечаев - это здорово, правда - но дело в том, что если бы было такое решение, то уж за многое множество лет оно бы мне как-то попалось - не видел - может, конечно, просто не видел...

Comment: Я ошибся. Это не работает, так как это на самом деле: `if ( (SERVER_PORT != 443 OR REQUEST_FILENAME != -f) and REQUEST_URI != (.*) and REQUEST_URI != .html)`
Я решил задачу изменив только правило для редиректа на https. Добавил: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$`
То есть: `RewriteCond%{SERVER_PORT}!^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteRule.* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}[L,R=301]` Что скажете по поводу этого варианта?

Comment: продублировал на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BLCm54CE).

Comment: Не вижу условий из первого блока Вашего вопроса. Но пробуйте, смотрите - если Вас все устраивает, то закрывайте вопрос.